# Integral of log and exponential with power

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, laplace-transform, laplace-method

This integral sounds quite complex and I could not find an approximate equivalent. Any hopes for solving:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} x\log(1+x^2)\,e^{- B x}\,dx$$

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty } x \log \left(1+x^2\right) \exp (-B x) \, dx=\frac{2-2 \text{Ci}(B) (\cos
   (B)+B \sin (B))-B \cos (B) (\pi -2 \text{Si}(B))+\sin (B) (\pi -2 \text{Si}(B))}{B^2}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. Just out of curiosity : how did you get this result ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. From Mathematica.`LaplaceTransform[x*Log[1 + x^2], x, B]`  -> $\text{Ci}(B)$ and $\text{Si}(B)$ is cosine and sinus integral function

Comment: Oh my my...i was expecting something close to it..let me check @MariuszIwaniuk.. By the way what is after "-" in the end?

Comment: @KanwalZaidi MMA code `1/B^2 (2 - 2 CosIntegral[B] (Cos[B] + B Sin[B]) - 
   B Cos[B] (\[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[B]) + 
   Sin[B] (\[Pi] - 2 SinIntegral[B]))` for better copy.

Comment: Thanks alot @MariuszIwaniuk

Comment: From WA, we get $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} x\log(1+x^2)\,e^{- B x}\,dx=\frac{2 G_{1,3}^{3,1}\left(\frac{B^2}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0,0,\frac{3}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } B^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

For starters, substitute $x^2\mapsto x,~$ as follows :

> $$\begin{align}I
> ~&=~\quad\int_0^\infty~x~\ln(1+x^2)~e^{\large-Bx}~dx
> ~=~\frac12\quad\int_0^\infty\ln(1~+~x^2)~e^{\large-B\sqrt{x^2}}~d(x^2)~=~
> \\\\
> ~&=~\frac12~\int_0^\infty\quad\ln(1+x)~e^{\large-B\sqrt x}~dx
> ~=~\frac12~\bigg[\int_0^\infty\ln(1+Ax)~e^{\large-B\sqrt x}~dx\bigg]_{A=1}
> ~=~\frac{J(1)}2
> \end{align}$$

Now, employ differentiation under the integral sign :

> $$\begin{align}J'(A)
> ~&=~\int_0^\infty\frac x{1+Ax}~e^{\large-B\sqrt x}~dx
> ~=~\frac{d^2}{dB^2}~\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+Ax}~e^{\large-B\sqrt x}~dx~=~
> \\\\
> ~&=~\frac{d^2}{dB^2}~\bigg\{\frac1A~\bigg[\sin\frac B{\sqrt A}\bigg(\pi-2\text{ Si }\frac B{\sqrt A}\bigg)-2~\cos\frac B{\sqrt A}\text{ Ci }\dfrac B{\sqrt A}\bigg]\bigg\},
> \end{align}$$

which, when integrated with regard to **A**, yields the rather beautiful expression :

> $$\frac{J(A)}2~=~\frac{d^2}{dB^2}\bigg[\text{ Ci}^2~\dfrac B{\sqrt A}+\text{ Si}^2~\dfrac B{\sqrt A}-\pi\text{ Si }\dfrac B{\sqrt A}\bigg],$$

which, when evaluated at $A=1,~$ gives $~I~=~\dfrac{J(1)}2~=~\dfrac{d^2}{dB^2}~\bigg[\text{ Ci}^2~B+\text{ Si}^2~B-\pi\text{ Si }B\bigg],$

coinciding with the result provided by **Mariusz Iwaniuk** in the comments. *QED*.